# Replace a 2017 Touch Bar MacBook Pro retina display with late 2013 MacBook Pro retina display?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen

I cracked my 2017 Touch Bar MacBook Pro display, and I have an old Late 203 MacBook Pro with a screen in good working condition.

I am wondering if it's possible to replace the display of the new one with the old one.

Answer (score 2):

No. The displays in the two MacBook Pro are not compatible and can not be interchanged. Also, the two models vary a lot in overall hardware design.

You can refer to the iFixit Display Replacement guides for more details:

- [MacBook Pro 13" Retina Display Late 2013 Display Assembly Replacement](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Retina+Display+Late+2013+Display+Assembly+Replacement/27666)
- [MacBook Pro 13" Touch Bar 2016 & 2017 Display Replacement](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Touch+Bar+2016+&+2017+Display+Replacement/104418)